# Stored procedure for the Exponential in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, exponential, postgresql-9.0

In PostgreSQL I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR: argument for function "exp" too big
SQL state: 22003
```

I need to write a stored procedude for the Exponential as:

- If `exp(value)` throws argument for function "exp" too big
- then return 0
- else return `exp(value)`

Please help me how to process this stored procedure.

Comment: +1 Thanks for including your Pg version and cleaning up your earlier question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's happening:

```
regress=# SELECT exp(NUMERIC '6000');
ERROR:  argument for function "exp" too big
```

You're passing an unrealistically large value to `exp()`. It's way too big to overflow a `float8` (double) and can only be represented as a `NUMERIC`. Even there, there's a limit, and you hit it when you go above `exp(5999)`.

For hard maths you might want to try [`PL/R`](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/), an in-database embedded version of the `R` language.

It's hard to say what to do, because you haven't really explained what the query is for, what the inputs to `exp` are supposed to be, etc.

Returning zero for an exponent that's too big is kind of crazy. Why?

---

To trap an exception, use [BEGIN ... EXCEPTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) in PL/PgSQL.

I've written the below function to return `NaN` ("not a number") instead of zero, as I think returning zero is just downright wrong. Change it if you need to. It might also make a little bit of sense to return `NULL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exp_if_possible(numeric) RETURNS numeric as $$
BEGIN
    RETURN exp($1);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN numeric_value_out_of_range THEN
        RETURN 'NaN';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

The error code `numeric_value_out_of_range` was obtained by looking up the `SQLSTATE 22003` you get from the out-of-range `exp` in [Appendix A. PostgreSQL Error Codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) in the Pg manual. You'll see a link to it in the documentation about `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION`.

---

I initially said that if it's to be done at all it should be done by testing the input, but I think I was wrong about that. There's no guarantee that the limit will be `exp(6000)`, so you're right to use exception handling even though it'll be slow and clumsy. I'll update this response with an exception handling version in a sec.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crazy_exp(numeric) RETURNS numeric AS $$
-- exp(6000) and above will throw 'argument for function "Exp" too big
-- For such cases, return zero because [insert explanation here]
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 < 6000 THEN exp($1) ELSE 0 END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crazy_exp(float8) RETURNS float8 AS $$
-- float8 goes out-of-range above about exp(600)
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 <= 600 THEN exp($1) ELSE 0 END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;
```

That's *massively* more efficient than trapping the "out of range" exception in PL/PgSQL, and makes your intent clearer too.

Comment: hi mighty it is not possible to write a stored procedure too?

Comment: @Sathish Yes, as shown above. DON'T DO IT though. This approach feels so wrong it hurts. Why on earth are you trying to do this? What's the real problem you are trying to solve? It seems like you've got a problem, you've decided this is the solution, and you're asking how to create your solution. What's the underlying problem, the real issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Sathish Thanks for deleting your earlier effort at this question.

Comment: fine mighty but the above stored procedure crazy_exp(5999.2) ?

Comment: @Sathish ... returns zero like you said it should. I don't understand what you are asking with your last comment. I also really think you should edit your question and explain *why* you want to do this, it might help come up with cleaner/better solutions.

Comment: @Sathish OK, so it's clipping a little early. Change <= 5999 to < 6000. Come to think of it there's a problem with this design though, will update the question in a second.

Comment: @Sathish Updated with error handling version - **much** slower, but safer if the limit changes in a future version. I still think this whole design is utterly wrong.

Comment: actually im getting the argument for function "exp" too big for many cases thats why i decided to wrok on stored procedure on this

Comment: @Sathish Sure, but this changes an error to giving the wrong results instead. That hardly seems an improvement. Should you be returning NULL? At least that'd make a little bit of sense if you interpreted it as "unknown/unknowable". The correct result would be `NaN`.

Comment: fair mighty where you fonud this "numeric_value_out_of_range"  i was searching for this word since but im not able to find ........